# safari and chrome media query doesn't function

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I have a bootstrap menu that collapses upon making the browser smaller. I also have a second menu, that vanishes on small devices and appeares in the collapsed first menu. It functions good in Firefox, but not in safari and chrome. Here is my code:

```css
 li.hideshow {
   display: none;
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 500px),
 screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
   img.smallResolution {
     max-width: 220px;
   }
   li.hideshow {
     display: block;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#point1">publisher</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#point2">advertiser</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#point3">news</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#point4">contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hideshow"><a href="#">point5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hideshow"><a href="#">point6</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hideshow"><a href="#">point7</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I searched so much but i didn't find the answer. I hope someone can see what's wrong here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to define the screens with each size definition.

This should do the trick:

```css
li.hideshow {
  display: none;
}
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 500px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  img.smallResolution {
    max-width: 220px;
  }
  li.hideshow {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#point1">publisher</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#point2">advertiser</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#point3">news</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#point4">contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hideshow"><a href="#">point5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hideshow"><a href="#">point6</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hideshow"><a href="#">point7</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: tried it: the code functions only in chrome. FF and Safari don't show the .hideshow class in the collapsed menu :(

Comment: i removed the line with (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1). now it functions in FF and Chrome, but not in Safari.

Comment: Safarai is far more sensitive to error's than the other's I would chekc your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px),
       only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
@media (max-width: 500px), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: tried both: FF still functions, but safari and chrome show the second menu inside the first one on the full-width-screen (desktop) too. It seems as if they just ignore the display: none; :(

Comment: Why use pixel ratio: 1? For non high resolution display?

Comment: i tried this line (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) because it was offered as a solution on one of the forums, but it didn't function.

Comment: with this code it functions in FF and Chrome, but not in Safari: '@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    img.smallResolution {
        max-width: 220px;
    }
    li.hideshow {
        display: block;
    }
}'

Comment: Normally i use only this (with different resolution): @media (max-width: 500px). And it works everywhere.

Comment: yes, FF and Chrome are ok with this code, but Safari won't show the second menu in the collapsed menu. :(

Answer (score 0):

ok, i changed the max-width to 600px and now it functions in FF, Chrome AND SAFARI. I noticed that all these three browsers have their custom borders, whereby you can reduce the browser-window-width of FF the most, then comes Chrome, and then comes Safari.
Thank you @DCdaz and @Germano Plebani for your answeres.